# cannot create item with duplicate context menu id in extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, runtime-error, contextmenu

I am creating a new extension. And I add a context menu option via an extension in webpages.
But chrome developer mode throws an error, that is 'unchecked.runtime.lastError: cannot create an item with duplicate id `my id` '. but I gave that in unique id. how to fix that.?
this is my context creation method.

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "zm_mark_down_preview_beta",
    title: 'preview and edit',
    contexts: ["editable"]
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Chrome, you should create the context menu just once after install/update.

Use [`onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) event:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "zm_mark_down_preview_beta",
    title: 'preview and edit',
    contexts: ["editable"]
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can simply suppress the error by accessing [`lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#property-lastError) in the callback:

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "zm_mark_down_preview_beta",
  title: 'preview and edit',
  contexts: ["editable"]
}, () => chrome.runtime.lastError);
```